# Как вывести символьный массив из hashmap в textField

Tags: java, javafx, jtextfield, java-hashmap

Проблема заключается в том, что вывести его я могу, но когда я вывожу, я получаю вот такую картину

[image: В текстфилде первый ключ]

Что мне сделать, что бы у меня показывались символы массива, а не эти?

```
    private HashMap<Integer, char[]> map = new HashMap<>();



    char[] arrayOfChars =null;

    @FXML
    public void onEncrypt(){
        toArrays(text.getText());
         for (int i = 1; i<6 ;i++){

                if(i==1){
                    for(int j=0; j<5;j++){
                        char[] podArray =new char[5];
                        podArray[j] = arrayOfChars[j];
                        map.put(i,podArray);
                    }
                }
                if(i==2){
                     for(int j=5; j<10;j++){
                         char[] podArray =new char[5];
                         podArray[j-5] = arrayOfChars[j];
                         map.put(i,podArray);
                     }
             }
             if(i==3){
                 for(int j=10; j<14;j++){
                     char[] podArray =new char[5];
                     podArray[j-10] = arrayOfChars[j];
                     map.put(i,podArray);
                 }
             }
             if(i==4){
                 for(int j=15; j<20;j++){
                     char[] podArray =new char[5];
                     podArray[j-15] = arrayOfChars[j];
                     map.put(i,podArray);
                 }
             }
             if(i==5){
                 for(int j=20; j<25;j++){
                     char[] podArray =new char[5];
                     podArray[j-20] = arrayOfChars[j];
                     map.put(i,podArray);
                 }
             }
         }
        firstKey.setText(map.get(1).toString());
    }




    private void toArrays(String text) {
        arrayOfChars = text.toCharArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для вывода массива:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
char [] array = map.get(1);
for (char aChar : array) {
    sb.append(aChar);
    sb.append(" ");
}  
firstKey.setText(sb.toString());
```

Попутно скажу, что мне кажется, вы неправильно заполняете массив. Его инициализация и сохранение в `map` должно происходить вне цикла. Например, так:

```
if(i==1){
      char[] podArray =new char[5];
      for(int j=0; j<5;j++){
          podArray[j] = arrayOfChars[j];
      }           
      map.put(i,podArray);
}
```